# Install python igraph on mac

Tags: python, igraph

I executed the `brew install homebrew/science/igraph` 
When I execute `sudo pip3 install python-igraph`, I got the following error

```
Cannot find the C core of igraph on this system using pkg-config.
We will now try to download and compile the C core from scratch.
Version number of the C core: 0.7.1.post6
We will also try: 0.7.1

Using temporary directory: /private/tmp/pip-build-35vcjf7l/python-igraph/tmp/igraph.4cz7yjcl
Downloading igraph-0.7.1.tar.gz... 0.28%error: <urlopen error retrieval incomplete: got only 992 out of 2967134 bytes>
```

Can anyone help?
Many thanks

Comment: Now I install directly by sudo pip3 install https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/python-igraph/python-igraph-0.7.1-1.tar.gz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note this post assumes you have [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) installed and are trying to install on a Mac.**

To avoid any issues of python3/python2 I would recommend using python2 because that is what the igraph library is designed to work with. I executed the following codes on a mac and things worked fine.

Instructions to install igraph on python2, in your terminal execute these lines:

```
brew install cairo
brew install py2cairo
brew install igraph
```

Now this last line above line installs the C-core. Final terminal line is:

```
sudo pip install python-igraph
```

The above line installs igraph for *python2*,
note these lines take about 2 minutes to complete for me

Next open python2 or idle-from terminal (I used idle).

Mow check in python REPL shell...

```
import igraph.test
igraph.test.run_tests()
```

If everything looks ok then you've got igraph in python working for you

Also check this one:

```
from igraph import *
g = Graph.Famous("petersen")
plot(g)
```

You should get a nice graphic of the peterson graph (red nodes, small graph)

Comment: I followed your guidelines but I am facing this error :   
```ImportError: dlopen(/Users/alexandreattia/Desktop/Work/py27_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/igraph/_igraph.so, 2): Symbol not found: _iconv
  Referenced from: /Users/alexandreattia/Desktop/Work/py27_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/igraph/_igraph.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/alexandreattia/Desktop/Work/py27_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/igraph/_igraph.so ```   
Do you have any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: Do you have homebrew installed and are you on a mac? Rather than the error only, please provide the command you called which created the error, this will help me help you.

Comment: Yes I am on Mac (High Sierra), I have homebrew (1.3.6). This error was created when I run on python 2.7 `import igraph`. Thank you very much

Comment: Hmm, first thing I would do is look at the log from when homebrew installed igraph on your machine. My first guess is that the location homebrew is using is different from the location that your python 2.7 environment is using.

Comment: How can I change the homebrew location to install in my python 2.7 virtual environment.  igraph is installed at `/usr/local/Cellar/igraph/0.7.1_6` and python is at `/Users/alexandreattia/Desktop/Work/py27_venv/bin/python`

Comment: what is the location of the first python binary in your $PATH environment variable? I think this is where homebrew is looking-not 100% sure but it seems so. How are you invoking your python binary when you get the error?

Comment: also to see your configurations in homebrew you can run: `brew config`

Comment: I am just calling `python`.   
`brew config` outputs `Python: /usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python => /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7`

Comment: I don't know how to find the first python binary in my $PATH environment variable. I think it's: `'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7'`(found in my `sys.path`) which is indeed different than the homebrew. Do you know how to fix this ? Thanks for your help !

Comment: The easiest way to fix this is to use the python environment that is used by homebrew rather than the other option. To do this you would invoke with a simple `python` call in the terminal to get a REPL shell.

Comment: It works, thank you very much! I just had to create a new python 2.7 virtualenv with the python path from the `brew config`.