# Python: read adjacency matrix from file for igraph

Tags: python, igraph, adjacency-matrix

My question is very simple, but I really cannot find it on the web!

I have the adjacency matrix of a weighted-directed graph which is like:

```
1    2    3    4    
5    2    4    6  
3    5    6    2
4    6    7    8
```

so the element of column i and row j, shows the weight of the link between node i and j.

How can I read this file (which can be in txt or csv format) as a matrix to use in igraph?
I want to find the number of clusters. So, I want sth like this:
    g.community_multilevel()
if g is my matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you already have igraph and cairo installed on your machine. If not and you are on a mac see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45667147/install-python-igraph-on-mac/46335152#46335152). The method you want to use is `Read_Adjacency()` which is documented [here](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.Graph-class.html#Read_Adjacency). To read in your graph I used something like this python code:

```
import igraph 
from igraph import * 
g=Graph.Read_Adjacency(f="soAdj",sep=None, comment_char='#',attribute="weighted")
plot(g, "readAdjSoExample.pdf",layout="circle")
```

and the plot will give something like this: 
    [image]

and you can access the weights to verify that they were read in correctly via command like: `g.es[3]` which gives result
`igraph.Edge(<igraph.Graph object at 0x10f614bf0>, 3, {'weighted': 4.0})`

The OP mentioned text vs csv format, the difference would be in which separator you include as a string to the `sep=` argument to the method.